# NodeJS: Would App Run Faster if Freeze Objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, object

Most of my objects/functions do not change. Would the application run faster if I freeze most of the objects via `Object.freeze(object)`? Or will it make no difference at all?

Comment: I've recently created a node js library [fast-freeze](https://github.com/node-muneem/fast-freeze) which make an object read only using nested functions. In result, accessing of properties become faster than even the normal unfreezed object. Though it looks ugly to use it with vanilla js but worth to try.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Freezing (and sealing) causes a signficant performance hit instead of a gain across various browsers. Just take a [look](http://jsperf.com/object-freeze-perf) at [some](http://jsperf.com/freeze-vs-seal-vs-normal/3) of the jsperf [benchmarks](http://jsperf.com/object-freeze).

EDIT: [Here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=115960)'s the relevant issue for v8.

EDIT2: The linked issue was fixed as of Dec 10, 2014. Frozen objects don’t have any performance hit according to the fix.

> Optimize Object.seal and Object.preventExtensions
>
> They both now run fast (due to utilizing transitions instead of always
> creating new maps) and sealed or non-extensible objects can stay in
> fast mode after transitioning.

Comment: If you read that bug in detail, it argues that some of the benchmarks are measuring the wrong thing and that `Object.freeze()` has now been fixed in Chrome so it isn't slow like it used to be.  `Object.seal()` has apparently not yet been fixed.

Comment: Using Chrome 36.0.1941.0 32-bit on Windows NT 6.3 64-bit, there seems to be no different between the three. I will go test it directly on my Nodejs server.

Comment: Ok, using Nodejs, freezing the object seems to be 30-40% slower than regular on my computer.

Comment: @RainingChain - keep in mind that new node releases occasionally incorporate newer v8 so at some point you will see a convergence in Node versions between frozen and normal objects the same as we're seeing in Chrome at this point. From the [v8 changelog](https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/ChangeLog) they apparently 'made Object.freeze fast' in version 3.19.4 of v8. You can use `process.versions.v8` to get the v8 version for Node. Node v 0.11 is well beyond, but it appears 0.10.25 is 3.14.5 with some backport fixes. Here's looking forward to a stable new major node release soon.

Comment: Chrome is now slightly faster (in the order of <1%) in iterating frozen objects. I've noticed a similar ironic issue yet to be fixed with Object.seal().